# dplyr: conditional column selection using select_if()

Tags: r, dplyr

A follow-up from a previous question...

How to select all columns based on a type, with the exception of one column based on a select helper function?

```
select_if(iris, is.numeric, vars(-contains("Width")))
Error: No tidyselect variables were registered
```

I have it within a nested dataframe, and am running it over a purrr::map() which slightly complicates the workflow options:

```
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  nest %>% 
  mutate(data = map(data, ~ .x %>% select_if(is.numeric) %>% mutate(count = sum(rowSums(.))))) %>%
  mutate(data = map(data, ~ .x %>% select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
                      mutate_all(funs((. / count) * 100 )))) %>%

  unnest
```

Comment: Note: the reason for the conditional select() is on the "count" column, which is being included in the second mutate when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest and clearest way to do this is to pipe together 2 `select` functions:

```
iris %>%
    select_if(is.numeric) %>%       # Select all numeric columns
    select(-contains('Width')) %>%  # Then drop 'Width' column(s)
    head

  Sepal.Length Petal.Length
1          5.1          1.4
2          4.9          1.4
3          4.7          1.3
4          4.6          1.5
5          5.0          1.4
6          5.4          1.7
```

This works even inside a `map` function:

```
iris %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>% 
    nest %>% 
    mutate(data = map(data, ~ .x %>%
                          select_if(is.numeric) %>%
                          select(-contains('Width')) %>%
                          mutate(count = sum(rowSums(.))))) %>%
    mutate(data = map(data, ~ .x %>%
                          select_if(is.numeric) %>%
                          select(-contains('Width')) %>% 
                          mutate_all(funs((. / count) * 100 )))) %>%

    unnest 

# A tibble: 150 x 4
   Species Sepal.Length Petal.Length count
   <fct>          <dbl>        <dbl> <dbl>
 1 setosa          1.58        0.433   100
 2 setosa          1.52        0.433   100
 3 setosa          1.45        0.402   100
 4 setosa          1.42        0.464   100
 5 setosa          1.55        0.433   100
 6 setosa          1.67        0.526   100
 7 setosa          1.42        0.433   100
 8 setosa          1.55        0.464   100
 9 setosa          1.36        0.433   100
10 setosa          1.52        0.464   100
# ... with 140 more rows
```

Comment: Agreed, please see my above added reprex, I believe the issue is in how to carry out the select with a map() function, which is why I was hoping to do it within the same select_if()

Comment: @CoreyPembleton You can actually pipe together multiple `select` statements inside the `map` function. There's no need for it to be a single `select_if` function.

Comment: Thank you @divibisan, this is very helpful. I realized (see comment above) that I was asking the wrong question, as what I really wanted is for the "count" column to not be included in the mutate_all() call (because I need the counts but 100 is the result of count/count *100. Either way this is has been very helpful, and has gotten me "close enough"...I'll have to perfect it later!

Answer (score 0):

```
select_if(iris[, !colnames(iris) %in% ("Sepal.Width")], is.numeric)
    Sepal.Length Petal.Length Petal.Width
1            5.1          1.4         0.2
2            4.9          1.4         0.2
3            4.7          1.3         0.2
4            4.6          1.5         0.2
5            5.0          1.4         0.2
```